# How to filter list in asp.net/vb.net using linq

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have a list of class

How can I filter on some condition..I am applying following it is working when value gets exact match

```
        Dim result = obj.OfType(Of clsEmrItmMstr)().Where(Function(s) s.GenName Like         txtserach.Text)
        grddetails.DataSource = result
        grddetails.DataBind()
```

where "clsEmrItmMstr" is my class name and "GenName"  is field in class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of the [`Like`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/swf8kaxw.aspx) operator you could simply use `String.Contains`:

```
Dim result = obj.OfType(Of clsEmrItmMstr)().
    Where(Function(s) s.GenName.Contains(txtserach.Text))
```

With `Like` you need `*` as wildcard, so this should work:

```
Dim result = obj.OfType(Of clsEmrItmMstr)().
    Where(Function(s) s.GenName Like String.Format("*{0}*", txtserach.Text))
```

(assuming that you want to find all objects where the `GenName` contains the text entered in the `TextBox`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Contains` function

```
Dim result As dynamic = obj.OfType(Of clsEmrItmMstr)().Where(Function(s) s.GenName.Contains(txtserach.Text))
grddetails.DataSource = result
grddetails.DataBind()
```